# Why is the `_Generic` keyword in my macro not working?

Tags: c, macros, printf, clang, c11

Probably I'm doing some very basic thing wrong here, but I just cannot figure out what that could be. I can explain my code snippet, but I think it is pretty obvious what I'm trying to do here: create a type-generic macro overload "print function" for my `DynamicArray`'s `dynarr_printf` method. The question is: why isn't it working?

Thanks in advance!

***ENV:***

```
// Mac OS X 10.9.2
// Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
cc -Wall -v -g -std=c11  -I/usr/local/include -c -o build/tmp/main.o main.c
```

***CODE:***

```
void
__dynarr_printf(DynamicArray *dynarr,
                void (*print_func)(int, void*));

#define __line_fmt__(fmt) "    [%d] " fmt "\n"

static inline void
__dynarr_printf_i(int i, int *v)
{
    printf(__line_fmt__("%d"), i, *v);
}

// tons of type specific functions ...

static inline void
__dynarr_printf_def(int i, void *v)
{
    printf(__line_fmt__("ptr(%p)"), i, v);
}

#define __dynarr_typef(type) _Generic((type), int: __dynarr_printf_i,     \

                                              // tons of type specific funcs ...

                                          default: __dynarr_printf_def)

#define dynarr_printf(dynarr, type) \
     (__dynarr_printf(dynarr, __dynarr_typef(type)))
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
main.c:102:5: error: expected expression
    dynarr_printf(dynarr, float);
    ^
./dynarr.h:168:31: note: expanded from macro 'dynarr_printf'
     (__dynarr_printf(dynarr, __dynarr_typef(type)))
                              ^
./dynarr.h:157:45: note: expanded from macro '__dynarr_typef'
#define __dynarr_typef(type) _Generic((type), int: __dynarr_printf_i,     \
                                            ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Don't use leading underscores, particularly double leading underscores, for your own identifiers. All such identifiers are reserved to the implementation (i.e., the compiler and the runtime library).

Comment: @KeithThompson okay, thanks for the tip, I will fix that in my code base!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of a generic selection is:

**`_Generic`** **`(`** *assignment-expression* **`,`** *generic-assoc-list* **`)`**

(For the definition of a *generic-assoc-list* and more information about generic selections, see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.5.1.1.)

The first "operand" is an expression, not a type name. It selects on the type of that expression.

If the type is always scalar, you could change

```
_Generic((type), ...)
```

to

```
_Generic((type)0), ...)
```

Comment: Of course, thank you! Is there any kind of *trick* I can use in my situation? It would be quite ugly to pass a data with the type the array is holding.. :P

Comment: @ChrisDodd `a` is a `DynamicArray*`, which is a typdef'd struct. It's type won't match the data it is holding.. or am I misunderstood something in your line?

Comment: @PeterVaro: I've added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @PeterVaro: I was misunderstanding what you were doing.  Assumedly, the `DynamicArray` object must contain something that indicates the type?

Comment: @KeithThompson that is bloody awesome, you are a genius, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisDodd nope it has a `void*` pointing to an array, where the data is stored

Comment: A compound literal would even more general `_Generic((type){ 0 }, ...`